# Is there a Windows API hook for "this application wants attention"?

Tags: winapi, notifications, windows-xp

In Windows XP, when a program wants the user's attention, it'll flash its taskbar button orange.  Anyone with an IM program is probably familiar with this behavior.  But when I'm playing a fullscreen-mode game, I don't see that, and messages go unanswered.

Now I'm writing a game engine of my own, and I'd like to be kind to my users.  Is there any Windows API call I can write a hook for that will notify my program whenever any other program just set its taskbar button to "orange flashing mode"?  That way, I could notify the user when it happens.

I'd be surprised if this isn't available.  I saw a Mac OS Classic screensaver that was able to do this way back in the mid-90s.  That's where I got the idea from.

Comment: personally, if i'm playing a game full-screen, i do not want to be interrupted. Interruptions can get you killed!

Comment: true I sometimes even get annoyed when steam has its little friend pop-up thing come up.

Comment: I'm not thinking of interruptions. More like an unobtrusive line of text, much like receiving a team chat message.  "Bob (Yahoo! Messenger) wants your attention." Then you get to decide whether or not to talk to Bob, instead of logging off 2 hours later and discovering you missed an old friend.

Comment: That doesn't sound too harmful.

Comment: What's the rationale behind closing this question?  This question is asked more clearly than its duplicate, and has a better answer already than the one on its duplicate.  Is this one closed just because it came later?

Comment: What I'm getting at is, how about closing the other one?

Comment: Reopened, since people seem to like it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is such a thing. You might be able to achieve it with [API hooking](http://www.google.com/search?q=API+hooking), although I'm not sure Vista will allow you to do that. Works on XP though.

There are however a few other ideas in this direction that might be "the next best thing":

- Don't take exclusive ownership of sound devices, so that sounds from other programs can be heard. I'm not sure how this is done, but some games block other sounds, some don't;
- Allow user to switch away from your game with ALT-TAB and other key combinations;
- If another window tries to become active, allow it to and gracefully minimize;

Other general tips include:

- Try to keep minimize/restore times down. I don't know anything about game programming, but for some games this takes ages.
- Properly restore picture when minimizing/restoring. Some games have issues with this.
- Auto-pause on minimize. If it's a network game and not possible to pause, perhaps send a message to other players so they know.
- Somewhat unrelated, but I love it when games show the clock somewhere (real clock, not some game time). This way I can easily tell if I should go to bed already without minimizing the program. :)

Comment: All very good ideas. Personally, programs that disable ALT-TAB, ALT-F4, or other basic functionality drive me up the wall.  If the user tries to do something and the application programmer says "I'm sorry Dave...", how is that any better than writing malware?

Comment: Vista or 7 have no issues with API hooking as long as the process is not a protected process. meaning you can't hook protected processes.